# Python regex re.sub substitution to as desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Using Python 3 consider this regex:

```
[\||JI|\[|\]NL\||JI|\[|\]]
```

This will be deployed against a string such as:

```
INLI VERONICA HD / DISNEY XD
```

Python used:

```
import re

new_string = re.sub("[\||JI|\[|\]NL\||JI|\[|\]]", "", old_string)
print(new_string)
```

Expected output:

```
VERONICA HD / DISNEY XD
```

Actual output:

```
NL VEROCA HD / DSEY XD
```

To ad some context, `NL` could be wrapped in any combination of the characters `J`, `I`, `|`, `[` and `]`, hence the either or options supplied in the regex. Anyone suggest how to amend to get the desired output?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
[][|JI]*NL[][|JI]*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8udhjc/1). *Details*:

- `[][|JI]*` - zero or more `]`, `[`, `|`, `J` or `I` chars
- `NL` - `NL` string
- `[][|JI]*` - zero or more `]`, `[`, `|`, `J` or `I` chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XIgh9W):

```py
import re
old_string = "INLI VERONICA HD / DISNEY XD"
new_string = re.sub(r"[][|JI]*NL[][|JI]*", "", old_string).strip()
print(new_string)
# => VERONICA HD / DISNEY XD
```